# How to change the prompt

Tags: ruby, command-prompt, configure, irb

I am trying to configure the prompt characters in ripl, an alternative to interactive ruby (irb). In irb, it is done using `IRB.conf[:DEFAULT]`, but it does not seem to work with ripl. I am also having difficulty finding an instruction for it. Please guide to a link for an explanation or give a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring a dynamic prompt in ~/.riplrc:

```
# Shows current directory
Ripl.config[:prompt] = lambda { Dir.pwd + '> ' }
# Print current line number
Ripl.config[:prompt] = lambda { "ripl(#{Ripl.shell.line})> " }
# Simple string prommpt
Ripl.config[:prompt] = '>>> '
```

Changing the prompt in the shell:

```
>> Ripl.shell.prompt = lambda { Dir.pwd + '> ' }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you also tell me the commands for changing the prompt `|` in the continuation and the prompt `=>` in the result?

Comment: Those configurations respectively are Ripl.config[:multi_line_prompt] and Ripl.config[:result_prompt]. The first can be dynamic or a string and the second one can only be a string. For more docs: `gem install gem-man` and `gem man ripl`.

Answer (score 0):

> ripl loads your ~/.irbrc file, which
>   typically contains some irb specific
>   options (e.g. IRB.conf[:PROMPT]). To
>   avoid errors, you can install
>   ripl-irb, which catches calls to the
>   IRB constant and prints messages to
>   convert irb configuration to ripl
>   equivalents.

http://rbjl.net/44-ripl-why-should-you-use-an-irb-alternative

Comment: I have `ripl/irb` required, and when I do `IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:DEFAULT] = ...`, which works in irb, it returns an error saying that `Object::IRB` is not defined.

Comment: You need to require ripl/irb at the beginning of ripl i.e. `ripl -rripl/irb` or put it in your ~/.riplrc for it to work correctly.